# Dell XPS 13 Plus 9320: Horizontal lines (static) after installing latest release from oem-somerville-tentacool-meta

Tags: dell, xps

As the title suggests, I'm seeing horizontal lines on my display - static looking. The lines sometimes appear where the cursor is located.

The issue is intermittent and I was first concerned of hardware damage to the display. I ran both display diags: UEFI advanced and (hold) "D" + Power on.

Results look great with these tests.

I looked at the logs for APT and noted that there was a more infrequent update to `oem-somerville-tentacool-meta` that occurred right before this started happening and I'm beginning to suspect this package: `22.04Ubuntu6`

I wanted to downgrade to Ubuntu5, but it's not listed running
`apt list --all-versions`. I'm confused by the downgrade process and how these OEM repositories are managed, TBH.

However, I do see this version (and others) in the changelog:
`usr>share>doc>oem-somerville-tentacool-meta`

I'm frankly guessing about correlation between this update and my display issues. I'm hoping this thread finds someone else experiencing the same.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

I took everyone's advice and downgraded to kernel 5.15 which seems to correct the issue. To make my life easier during system boot, I purged 5.19 using:

`sudo apt purge <kernel>`

`sudo apt autoremove --purge`

I take it that everyone's SOP is to `sudo apt full-upgrade`? I see that can cause some issues

For the short term, I'm going to be installing piece meal via the package manager.

My experience with Dell support was not good. I understand the tiered support often cannot assist at level one, but there seems to be no Linux specific escalation personnel. Luckily, we're savvy

**Update 2**

I have been testing RC kernels and began to see good behavior with `5.19.0.3035-generic`. I.e., no artifacts with an unedited grub file.

[https://people.canonical.com/~khfeng/lp2002986-2/](https://people.canonical.com/%7Ekhfeng/lp2002986-2/)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2007516

I also received a phone call from Dell's Resolution Expert Center. Great experience chatting with a knowledgeable engineer who is tracking this bug. There is just a lot of red tape before a user can get to this next level. The official fix is to still add a parameter to `etc/default/grub`.

**This line**
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

**Becomes**
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"`

I can confirm that this also works.

Comment: Hi, I have the same PC model, same OS, and the same issue since last weekend. Please, comment DELL forum as well so that DELL community sees it's not only my problem. https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Horizontal-lines-appearing-on-my-display-Ubuntu/m-p/8353821#M159112

By the way I also opened a post on askubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455653/horizontal-colored-lines-appearing-on-display-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1#comment2544946_1455653

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and I also posted here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456219/problems-after-updates-on-dell-xps-plus-9320) and on Dell community (https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Problems-after-Ubuntu-updates-on-Dell-XPS-Plus-9320-Developer/m-p/8354773#M107228). Only other potential clues I have: I also got a weird BIOS update at around the same time that was apparently an error on Dell's part (https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-dell/issues/160) and a commenter on my Ask Ubuntu post noted that the update from kernel 5.15 to 5.19 happened almost simultaneously.

Comment: One potential clue: booting from kernel version 5.15.0 via the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" option in GRUB prevents the problem (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455653/horizontal-colored-lines-appearing-on-display-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: There is now a temporary fix over on the main thread for this problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455653/horizontal-colored-lines-appearing-on-display-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: @karel Yes, as I indicated above.

Comment: Hi all. We have identified this issue to be related to PSR2 being enabled in the 5.19 linux kernel by default, which introduces the issue mentioned in this question. We are tracking this issue in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2007516. For anyone who have this issue on your XPS 9320 and have the ability to test kernels, please try the test kernels posted at https://people.canonical.com/~khfeng/lp2007516/, and leave your test results in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2007516. If you'd like to help but not sure how to, please reach out to me, thanks!

Comment: @AnthonyWong I installed the test kernel and the issue returned.