Screen flickering DELL XPS 13 9340
I have a DELL XPS 13 9340 (New Version) and I have installed Ubuntu 22.04. One week ago, I notice some screen flickering (horizontal colored lines appear when moving the mouse).
I have reformated the hard drive and installed a dual boot Windows & Ubuntu (in order to check the issue with Windows). The problem disappears. But today fllickering appears again when using Ubuntu. I have no problem with Windows. If I boot my computer with the Ubuntu USB key, the problem disappears.
I suspect that an update version of Ubuntu is installed and produces this flickering.
Many thanks for your help.

You might want to see: https://hatchjs.com/ubu...

Or this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455653/horizontal-colored-lines-appearing-on-display-ubuntu-22-04 There is a lot of blabla in the link above, and no attempt for solution.

Dear John and vanadium, I have tried the grub solution explained here: https://gist.github.com/Jeckerson/375db1a2fa364cbaa906847c00e8b3bb and it works. Flickering has disappeared. Curiously, before fixing the bug, I have used my TV with a HDMI cable and I noticed that there is at the same time no flickering in the TV, but flickering continue on my laptop screen.  Many thanks, Thierry

I had the same problem on my Dell XPS 13 9340 (2024) : screen flickering when mouse is moved. It happened just after a kernel upgrade (from 6.5.0 to 6.8.0).
I downgraded the kernel and it fixed the problem.
Here how I did it:
Check image version : I had 6.8 (latest) and 6.5
dpkg -l | grep linux-image

Remove latest (image plus headers)
sudo apt purge linux-image-6.8.0-40-generic
sudo apt purge linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic
reboot

Hope this helps,
Regards,
E.

Many thanks for your help. I have already fixed the issue by trying the grub solution explained here: gist.github.com/Jeckerson/375db1a2fa364cbaa906847c00e8b3bb. Yes you have right that the problem comes from the fact that the kernel has changed. Many thanks.

Had the same issue on XPS 13 with Ubuntu 24.04.
The issue is fixed by upgrading to the oem kernel:
sudo apt install linux-oem-24.04
... or you need to wait until the issue is planned to be fixed in "6.8.0-45.45 or later".
Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2062951/comments/70
